# cannot understand while in Javascript programme?

Tags: javascript, events, while-loop

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 10: Example 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="usa.gif" onclick="changeImg(this)" />
        <img src="mexico.gif" onclick="changeImg(this)" />
        <script>
            var myImages = [
                "usa.gif",
                "canada.gif",
                "jamaica.gif",
                "mexico.gif"
            ];

            function changeImg(that) {
                var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
                while (that.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) {
                    newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
                }
                that.src = myImages[newImgNumber];
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The author of the programme says in the explanation of the code:
the purpose of while loop is to ensure that you don't select the same image as the current one. If the string contained in `myImages[newImgNumber]` is found inside the src property of the current image, you know it's the same and that you need to get another random number.You keep looping until you get a new image, at which point `myImages[newImgNumber]` will not be found in the existing arc, and -1 will be returned by the `indexOf()` method, breaking out of the loop.

I simply cannot get the explanation.Can anyone explain me the same in other words? The code is from Beginning Javascript 5e,Jeremy Mcpeak,Chapter Events.

Comment: everyone here will give you the same explanation as the author has given. Which part are you not able to understand? Perhaps [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) will help.

Comment: Alas, in reality everyone here will try to guess which part OP has found confusing. Most or all of them will be wasting their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random() * 3` gives a number between 0 and 3. `myImages[newImgNumber]` gives the name of one of the image names in the array. If for example you call `changeImg(myImg)` and myImg is `<img src="usa.gif" />`, inside the function `that.src` is `"usa.gif"`, `that.src.indexOf("usa.gif")` (`"usa.gif".indexOf("usa.gif")`) will return 0, so the loop will continue and you'll get a new random number. At the next iteration it'll be `that.src.indexOf("canada.gif")`, which will return -1 since "canada.gif" is not found in "usa.gif", it will return -1 and it will exit the loop.

Comment: Can this program be written using for or if/else?If so,how?That will make it much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From indexOf() on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

The loop continues until a valid newImgNumber (index) is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the array like this:

```
myImages[0] = "usa.gif";
myImages[1] = "canada.gif";
myImages[2] = "jamaica.gif";
myImages[3] = "mexico.gif";
```

So when you get a random number between 0-3 you need to make sure your next image src in the slideshow is different from the current src being shown.

Answer (score 0):

- It generates a random number which it will use as the index in the `myImages` array
- `myImages[newImgNumber]` will retrieve the corresponding name of the randomly-retrieved image,
  so it takes this name and checks that it doesn't match the name in the `src` attribute.
  It does this by calling `indexOf` which returns the index in the context string where the passed-in (parameter) string is found; if not found then `indexOf` returns -1. For example `strA.indexOf(strB);` returns the index in *strA* where *strB* exists.
- so if the result of the `indexOf` call *isn't* -1 then the current randomly-retrieved image name matches* the name in the `src` attribute. Only if the result *is* -1 does this function consider them to be different names.

The `while` loop might be a little tricky to understand as it kind of approaches the problem back-to-front: it says that so long as the `indexOf` method *does* find the randomly-retrieved name, then it should randomly-retrieve another name and try that until `indexOf` *does* return -1, which implies that this randomly-retrieved name is new.

And if it's a new name then it makes it past the `while` loop whereupon it is then assigned to the `src` attribute.

[*] Using `indexOf` to determine if they're the same image is pretty weak. For example, if the existing `src` attribute was called, say, "not-usa.gif" then the condition in the above function would still indicate that it's the same name as "usa.gif", which is clearly wrong.